# Mover datos entre clases

Tags: java, mysql, lista

Hola a todos buenas tardes, quisiera me ayudaran a saber como puedo desarrollar mi idea.
tengo unas listas en una clase que hice para hacer la conexión a una base de datos. la cual es la siguiente:

```
package pkgfinal;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ConexionMySQL {
    Connection co;
    Statement stm;

    public ConexionMySQL(){

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/estaciones?user=admin&password=123";
            Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stm1 = co.createStatement();
            Statement stm2 = co.createStatement();
            Statement stm3 = co.createStatement();

            ResultSet l1 = stm1.executeQuery("select * from linea1");
            ResultSet l2 = stm2.executeQuery("select * from linea2");
            ResultSet l3 = stm3.executeQuery("select * from linea3");

            LinkedList ln1 = new LinkedList();
            LinkedList ln2 = new LinkedList();
            LinkedList ln3 = new LinkedList();

            while(l1.next())
                ln1.addLast(l1.getString(3));
            while(l2.next())
                ln2.addLast(l2.getString(3));
            while(l3.next())
                ln3.addLast(l3.getString(3));

            System.out.println("linea1: "+ln1);
            System.out.println("linea2: "+ln2);
            System.out.println("linea3: "+ln3);            
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConexionMySQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

como podemos ver yo hago la consulta:

```
ResultSet l1 = stm1.executeQuery("select * from linea1");
```

que es en donde absorbo todos los datos y los meto a mi lista, sin embargo. es aquí donde ya no se como hacer para extraer por asi decirlo solo una de las columnas de mi tabla, por ejemplo en dado caso en que yo quiera ***extraer solo los ID de mi tabla*** para usarlos en alguna otra función o en alguna otra clase y poder así jugar y manipular todos los datos de mi tabla pero cada uno por separado.
Espero haberme hecho entender. MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA.

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas a modificar tu consulta?

    ResultSet l1 = stm1.executeQuery("select id from linea1");

Comment: si, lo pense, pero se me complicaria y creo tendria que hacer demasiadas consultas en el caso de que quiera manejar los datos de las tablas.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es una manera de separar las queries de los objetos Java de manera elegante, busca un ORM, para que genere esas relaciones entre objetos y tu entidad relación, JPA con una implementación, Hibernate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Para abstraerte de toda la lógica de conexión a la BD lo que deberías hacer es, como bien ha dicho @rekiem87 es incluir un ORM, [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), para java funciona estupendamente y diría que es el mas extendido.

En cualquier caso lo suyo seria que por lo menos te definieras clases para cada una de las tablas que tengas, con sus atributos iguales a los campos de cada tabla y al hacer la consulta instancias un objeto de esa clase y lo rellenas con los distintos valores y lo vas agregando a tu lista.

En esencia, eso es lo que te va a hacer un ORM, aparte de facilitarte la vida a la hora de realizar las operaciones de CRUD, entre muchas otras ventajas. Es la manera mas optima de trabajar con BDs relacionales en java.